# Prove $\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{1+b^2+c^4}{a^+b^2+c^3}\geq 3$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, prove $$\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{1+b^2+c^4}{a+b^2+c^3}\geq 3$$
>   Additional info: We should only use Cauchy (preferred to used at least once and more than AM-GM) and AM-GM. We are not allowed to use induction.

*Things I have done so far*: My idea is about separating question into $3$ inequality and proving them one by one and then sum all of them to prove question inequality.So$$\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{1}{a+b^2+c^3} \geq 1$$$$\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{b^2}{a+b^2+c^3} \geq 1$$
$$\sum \limits_{cyc} \frac{c^4}{a+b^2+c^3} \geq 1$$

**UPDATE**

As Macavity pointed in comments, the separating idea is not useful because first inequality does not hold.So any hint for starting step is appreciated.

Comment: Note that the first of your three split equalities will not hold for all reals. Just take $a,b,c$ Large enough to see that.

Comment: @Macavity,thanks for pointing out.what about question inequality?,does it have counter example?

Comment: The problem statement looks good, can't find any counter eg readily.

Comment: @Macavity,what does SOS stand for?

Comment: In its basic form, expressing some expression as a Sum Of Squares, thereby certifying it is $\ge 0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, note
$$LHS = \sum_{cyc} \frac{(1+b^2+c^4)(a+b^2+c^3)}{(a+b^2+c^3)^2} \ge  \sum_{cyc} \frac{(1+b^2+c^4)(a+b^2+c^3)}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(1+b^2+c^4)} = \sum_{cyc} \frac{a+b^2+c^3}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$

As the denominators of the cyclic sum are now the same, it only remains to show that
$$\sum_{cyc} (a + b^2+c^3) \ge 3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \iff \sum_{cyc} a + \sum_{cyc} a^3 \ge 2\sum_{cyc} a^2$$
which follows from AM-GM as $a+a^3 \ge 2a^2$.

Comment: I am speechless,awesome proof.