# Prove ${\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{a^4+a^2+1}{a^6+a^3+1}\leq\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{3}{a^2+a+1}}$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers,Prove:$${\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{a^4+a^2+1}{a^6+a^3+1}\leq\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{3}{a^2+a+1}}$$
>
> Additional info: We should only use Cauchy and AM-GM.

*Things I have done so far:* For $a$ I can write using Cauchy inequality that$$(a^2+a+1)(a^6+a^3+1)\geq (a^4+a^2+1)^2$$$$\frac{a^2+a+1}{a^4+a^2+1}\geq \frac{a^4+a^2+1}{a^6+a^3+1}$$
So i should Prove this: $$\frac{3}{a^2+a+1}\geq\frac{a^2+a+1}{a^4+a^2+1}$$

Working on this inequality lead me to this$$(a-1)^2(a^2+a+1)\geq0$$

which is obviously true.So i can do the same thing for $b$ and $c$ to prove inequality.however I think $\frac{3}{a^2+a+1}\geq\frac{a^2+a+1}{a^4+a^2+1}$ could have counterexample(I'm trying to find it).

And using $\sum \limits_{cyc}$ confuses me and I think below inequality is not true.So this    is the reason I do it separately for $a$,$b$,$c$. $$(\sum \limits_{cyc}(a^2+a+1))(\sum \limits_{cyc}(a^6+a^3+1))\geq (\sum \limits_{cyc}(a^4+a^2+1))^2$$

Comment: As an aside, you could prove that inequality by using CS: $ ( 1 + 1 + 1 ) ( a^4 + a^2 + 1) \geq ( a^2 + a + 1 ) ^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your proof have a problem. Can I ask for the reason why you are looking for a counterexample?

And for the second one:
$$\begin{align}
\left(\sum \limits_{cyc}(a^2+a+1)\right)\left(\sum \limits_{cyc}(a^6+a^3+1)\right)
&\ge \left(\sum_{cyc}\left((a^2+a+1)(a^6+a^3+1)\right)^{1/2}\right)^2
\\&\ge \left(\sum_{cyc}(a^4+a^2+1)\right)^2,
\end{align}$$
so it holds. But it doesn't seem to help proving the problem.

Comment: well, i ran in to problem in past [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883587/prove-sum-limits-cyc-frac1b2c4ab2c3-geq-3?rq=1),my first inequality did not hold there.so it is for bad memories.

Comment: @user2838619 In this case, the term in the summation only depends on one variable, so seperating the inequality may helps.